# Compare values from a picklist

Tags: apex

I am new to Salesforce.

i have an object `item__c`.it has a picklist field named `Type__c` having values **T1,T2,T3,T4**.My requirement is when the selected value for `Type__c` field is **T2** or **T4** then some assignment operation should be done.

```
if(item__c.Type__c ==                  )
{
eachEvent.Item=eachEvent.WhoId;
}
```

Someone please help me out
Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to something in Apex? (You use the "apex" tag.) Where do you want to print anyway? In a Lightning component on a flexipage? Please be very specific with your question and show what you've already attempted to do.

Comment: Is this a multi-select picklist or a single value picklist?

Answer (score 1):

This expression:

```
item__c.Type__c
```

is likely to be interpreted by the Apex compiler as an [SObjectField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Schema_SObjectField.htm) token. This mechanism is made part of Apex to make code that references various fields compile-time checked.

Instead you need to use in the variable name of that type in the expression e.g.:

```
item__c item = ...;

if (item.Type__c == 'T2'...
```

Answer (score 0):

Keith C's answer is on the money here.

Adding to that, it may not save any typing this time but once you start trying to match a field against multiple values, it may help to use a `Set` instead.

So instead of something like

```java
if(myRecord.My_Field__c == 'T1' || myRecord.My_Field__c == 'T2'){
    // do work
}
```

You'd create a set and use `.contains()`

```java
Set<String> targetValues = new Set<String>{'T1', 'T2'};
if(targetValues.contains(myRecord.My_Field__c)){
    // do work
}
```